# filtering dataframe by value, new df gives "Keyerror: True"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with data like this:

```
employee      id       department
Jane Smith    12345    HR
Joe Smith     54321    IT
Lee Smith     52341    Admin
```

I create a dataframe like so:

```
df=pd.read_excel(filename)
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe of just the people in one department.

```
admin_folk = df[df['department'].str.contains('Admin').any()]
```

What I get is "KeyError: True"

Every post I see on filtering out dataframes by value use the above construct. I know that the construct returns a Boolean value, but I thought creating a new df carries all of the values for that row.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Remove `any` and use `df[df['department'].str.contains('Admin')]`?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Dangit. Thanks